# Load VR video multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, google-vr

I've some implementation of GoogleVR for iOS using Swift and it working well except from the fact that when I play the video multiple times the Transition View shows only the first time. How could I force to always show this transition view?

```
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: self.urlPost!)

videoVRView.load(from: url)
videoVRView.enableCardboardButton = true
videoVRView.enableFullscreenButton = true
videoVRView.enableInfoButton = false
videoVRView.hidesTransitionView = false
videoVRView.delegate = self

self.videoVRView.hidesTransitionView = false
self.videoVRView.displayMode =  GVRWidgetDisplayMode.fullscreenVR
self.currentDisplayMode =   GVRWidgetDisplayMode.fullscreenVR

if isPaused {
    videoVRView?.play()
} else {
    videoVRView?.pause()
}
```

Comment: Post your code for showing the transition view

Comment: Sorry @DanielLegler, this is my code.